# Equivalent of OnSessionStart for drupal

Tags: sessions, cookies

I am looking for the equivalent or at least a way to run a snippet of code only when the session starts and at now other time do i want this code run.  Can anyone help me with this?  Ive looked around and cant seem to find an answer and all i read about is how drupal is not good with sessions.

What im trying to do is:
Retrieve a value from the URL when the session starts and set a couple variables and cookies according to that variable.  I need to use those cookies throughout in order to retrieve correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use [hook_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) as it's the first hook called right after Drupal setup sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a reason why the hook_init runs twice instead of just once?

Answer (score 0):

You could use hook_init as @yvan suggested, but you would have to do a semaphore check as hook_init will be called on each and every page load.  Given that, it might be simpler to just use hook_preprocess_page which you might already be using and do something like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  global $user;

  if ($user->uid) {
    if (empty($_SESSION['YOURMODULE_cookies_set'])) {
      // set your cookies here
      $_SESSION['YOURMODULE_cookies_set']='cookies have been set'; // or TRUE :)
    }
  }

  // do any other preprocess stuff here

}
```

I added in the $user->uid to do the check for only logged in users as sessions with anonymous users are a dark art :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Is there a reason why the hook_init runs twice instead of just once?

Comment: If you have any fancy js or ajax going on, it may call it itself on that page as it's performing it's own page load then.